# How to render Unicode character in TCL/TK using X11 System

Tags: tcl, x11, tk-toolkit, xlib

I am trying to render a unicode character to draw a scissor mark (✂) in TCL/TK

I am using X11 API "void XwcDrawString(Display *display, Drawable d, XFontSet font_set, GC gc, int x, int y, wchar_t *string, int num_wchars)"

```
/* This is my code */

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

wchar_t scr = 0x2702;
char *fontname;
fontname = (char *)malloc(strlen("ISO10646-1") + 3);
if (fontname) sprintf(fontname, "%s,*", "ISO10646-1");
else fontname = ",*";

char **missing_charset_list_return;
int missing_charset_count_return;
char *def_string_return;
XFontSet font_set = XCreateFontSet(ths->display, fontname, &missing_charset_list_return, &missing_charset_count_return,  &def_string_return);

XwcDrawString(ths->display, ths->drawable, font_set, ths->gc, x, y, &scr, 1);
```

I expect scissor marks to get drawn here but instead some garbage text is printed.

I suspect I am setting wrong font name in API XwcDrawString (not sure though).
So, anybody could tell me what is wrong with this code or any other way to render unicode character.

Comment: You can't print that character in any font that uses `ISO8859-1` as an encoding; it simply _doesn't exist at all_ in that encoding!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is probably to use Tk's built in font engine, which does all the processing of weirdnesses with fonts, fallback characters, encodings and so on.

```
tkfont = Tk_GetFont(interp, tkwin, "Arial 14"); // Needs to be *something*

string = "\xe2\x9c\x82"; // UTF-8 encoded version of ✂

gcValues.foreground = XBlackPixel(ths->display, 0); // The colour to draw in
gcValues.font = Tk_FontId(tkfont); // Must match value passed to Tk_DrawChars
gc = Tk_GetGC(tkwin, GCForeground | GCFont, &gcValues);
Tk_DrawChars(ths->display, ths->drawable, gc, tkfont, string, strlen(string), x, y);
Tk_FreeGC(gc);

Tk_FreeFont(tkfont);
```

Comment: Note that the font name is _not_ an XLFD, but rather just `Arial 14`, a font family name and a size; experience with user scripts suggests that the simpler form is what 99.99% of all code prefers.

Comment: Hi Donal, above code certainly prints a unicode scissor mark. But unfortunately due to some situation, We need to use X11 APIs or methods to render unicode in our project. Is there any way you can suggest using X11.